# Efficient way to remove entries from a HashMap which values are in a specified range

Tags: java, hashmap

Is there a way to efficiently remove entries from a HashMap which values are in a specified range.

**I have following HashMap**

```
private Map<String, Long> accessTimes = new HashMap<>();
```

I would like to remove all entries where values are between 0 and 200.

Is it possible without iterating through them HashMap? Thank you for any tips.

Comment: You can use here `TreeMap`. It doesn't have the method to remove values in the given range. You need to iterate in this as well but you can iterate the set efficiently than `HashMap`. You can use `TreeMap#ceilingKey()` to find the keys in the given interval and delete it then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't do that without iterating over all keys in the map.

In a HashMap, entries are stored in buckets based on the hash code of the entry's key. Therefore, entries are not sorted which forces you to visit all elements to determine if one needs to be removed.

[image]